# Fast and complete ways to remove chloride from solution (sub ppb levels)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, precipitation

Main question: We are trying to reduce the chloride concentration in a solution to sub-ppb levels. I have to dissect a fruit fly in this solution so I am interested in removing any chloride that is released during that process. Is there a method that will reduce chloride below 1ppb in a timescale of minutes? The best I have found is the addition of silver nitrate, which will form silver chloride precipitate, but I am not sure how fast or how thorough this process is.

Background: I have been performing an experiment where I inject current into a cell of a fruit fly for a research project. For various reasons, we believe the cell membrane in one fruit fly line is more permeable to chloride than another fruit fly line and are trying to confirm this. We inject with 20nA of current for about 2 minutes and can't change these parameters much. We hope to completely replace the chloride anion in our bath with another anion, to see if this changes the readings we get from our injection. For that small of a current, I believe I need less than 1ppb chloride concentration for it not to participate much in carrying charge. It is very difficult to find a replacement salt that doesn't have a minor chloride impurity, so we are hoping to find ways to remove the chloride.

Comment: Yea, silver chloride is the least soluble common chloride salt I can come up with right off, and it is still soluble to about a ppm at room temperature.  So, when everyone tells you "silver chloride is insoluble", its pretty close, but there is always going to be _some_ solubility, in you case way too much.  Sorry, good luck!